# How do I map over an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
      posts: [],
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
  fetch("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=${API_KEY}")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({posts:data}));
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        { this.state.posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm trying to map the title of this news object but whenever i try to do that I get this error: TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function.
This is the picture of the object from data : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fnlg.png

Comment: do `console.log(data)` to see what is contains.. I am sure as per your error, `data` is not an array.

Comment: Here's the pic of data : https://i.imgur.com/ctvXXWA.png

Comment: @arup and per the question title "How do I map over an object", `data` is not an array either.

Comment: In the picture, the data is an array named articles, not an object named posts??

Comment: the posts is just a state which contains the data.

Comment: Here is the answer to your problem  [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50486586/7878987](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50486586/7878987)

Comment: @JonasWilms The OP thought, OPs use of `.map` is buggy, which is not. The OP assumed state has an array already, so why the map is not working. And there the OP has the mistake **the assumption**. The OP wants or knows the endpoints is going to give an array, because `posts: [],` .. I am aware of `data` is not array either. that is why I asked the OP to see what it looks like using `console.log()` so that the OP figures out by yourself it is map problem, rather datastrucure problem.

Comment: @JonasWilms Also your dup question mark to close the question doesn't makes sense to me. anyway it is your call..

Comment: @rockwire Is your problem solved?

Comment: The solution was in the setstate posts:data.articles

Answer (score 3):

Return an array of the object's using Object.keys()

```
{Object.keys(posts).map((item, i) => (
       <li key={i}>{posts[item].title}</li>
))}
```